# Laravel livewire using layout configuration as protected varaiables

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

in this link of `Livewire` as new feature which `calebporzio` provided that, we have:

```php
class Foo extends Component
{
    protected $layout = ['layouts.dashboard', 'body'];
    // or
    protected $layout = ['view' => 'layouts.dashboard', 'slot' => 'body'];

    protected $extends = ['layouts.dashboard', 'body'];
    // or
    protected $extends = ['view' => 'layouts.dashboard', 'section' => 'body'];

    //...
}
```

now i'm using this below code as default in `render()` function:

```php
public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.auth.login')
        ->extends('livewire.auth.app')
        ->section('content');
}
```

my issue is how can i simplified `view` by `livewire` layout feature? for example:

```php
protected $extends = ['view'=>'livewire.auth.app', 'section'=>'content'];
public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.auth.login');
}
```

and i get this error:

```
View [layouts.app] not found
```

Comment: You forgot the link, are you referring this? https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/2000 it's look like a feature spec, it's not implemented yet (if it will be).

Comment: They have merged the possibility to change the default layout from the config file though https://github.com/livewire/livewire/pull/2247 But not sure if it's already in the current release.